# apache camel @Produce method with Object argument instead of String

Tags: apache-camel, producer, spring-remoting

I am using Camel's POJO producing e.g.

{

```
public interface MyListener {
    String sayHello(String name);
}

public class MyBean {
    @Produce(uri = "activemq:foo")
    protected MyListener producer;

    public void doSomething() {
        // lets send a message
        String response = producer.sayHello("James");
    }
}
```

}

The interfaces using method sayHello with string object which used as body in the camel. However, If i try to use any other Object here i get exception from camel saying no TypeConvertor found for BeanInvocation for Conversion java.io.InputStream.

I know is the object was allowed it would have been mentioned somewhere. But i want to reason why it has been done like that and if there's a way to work-around this.

Answer (score 1):

I havent really used POJO messaging as yet. Maybe, an experienced user can help you better with this.

But from what I understand, it should be able to support any kind of object not just string.

The error that you're talking of seems to arise out of a mismatch down the route. I'm guessing there is some kind of issue with the consumption.

Can you please post the exact error stacktrace and the consumer method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with the same problem right now. The only obvious workaround so far is to use @EndpointInject instead of @Produce - then you get ProducerTemplate and publish any object:

```
    @EndpointInject(uri = "seda:report-send")
    ProducerTemplate reportSender;
```

Now you can do

```
    Object myObject = new Object();
    reportSender.sendBody(myObject);
```

Or even

```
    Object myObject = new Object();
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    headers.put("Subject", "Mail subject");
    headers.put("contentType", "text/plain");
    reportSender.sendBodyAndHeaders(myObject, headers);
```